# Express + TypeScript: Create type inference for response.locals

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I want to add types for my `response.locals`. It is used to append data to your request-response cycle.

What I tried

```
// ./types/express/index.d.ts
declare global {
    declare namespace Express {
        interface Response {
            locals: {
                userId: number;
            };
        }
    }
}
```

```
// tsconfig.json
    "compilerOptions": {
        "typeRoots": ["./types"],
    }
```

```
myController.post("/", async (request, response) => {
     // Can't get type in my controller
    const { userId } = response.locals; // <- userId is any
```

**Goal:** Get correct type inference for my `response.locals` variable

Versions:
`"express": "^4.17.1",`
`"@types/express": "^4.17.8",`
`"typescript": "^4.5.4"`

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49130179/5493813

Comment: @st.huber no, not really :/. I'm looking for a way to extend response.locals through an additional declaration file.

Comment: `typeRoots` option [has a default value](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#typeRoots); make sure to include it

Comment: Have you tried including it in the `files` section of tsconfig?

Comment: @ShamPooSham Yes, I tried to include it there. Didn't change anything, unfortunetaly.

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky How do you include the default option? I couldn't find the answer in the link you provided.

Comment: @Sirhennihau Actually, my bad, [this is harder than I thought it would be](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30855)

Answer (score 7):

Looking at `@types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts` we can see that there is a global namespace `Express` with some interfaces that we can extend. One of them is `Locals` :)

The solution:

`src/types.d.ts` (or similar, include it in tsconfig, eg in the "types" field)

```
declare global {
  namespace Express {
    interface Locals {
      anything: 'here'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What did it for me was `declare module 'express-serve-static-core'` instead of `namespace Express`

Answer (score 2):

Without a proper TypeScript background, I was able to compile the following (after some trial and error):

```js
import {Request, Response} from "express";
interface Locals extends Record<string, any> {
  userId: number;
}
interface MyResponse extends Response {
  locals: Locals;
}
export function middleware(request: Request, response: MyResponse) {
  const {userId} = response.locals;
  response.end(userId);
  return userId;
}
```

The declaration file (`.d.ts`) contains:

```js
export declare function middleware(request: Request, response: MyResponse): number;
```

so the `number` type was correctly inferred.

And it works when I use this middleware function in `express`.

Comment: `userId` is still assumed as `any` by TypeScript. Yes, it compiles. But I don't achieve type-safety this way.

Comment: I have edited my answer.